# How to copy one Graphics Object into another

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, graphics, gdi+

I am trying to copy the contents of one graphics object to another, but the only was I have been able to find is based on using `GDI32.DLL`, which i would rather avoid using if possible.

Does anyone know how/if this is possible using managed code?  I don't mind if answers are in C# or VB.Net.

Here is what I currently have:

```vb
Private Sub CopyGraphics()
    Dim srcPic As Graphics = pnl.CreateGraphics

    Dim srcBmp As New Bitmap(pnl.Width, pnl.Height, srcPic)
    Dim srcMem As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(srcBmp)

    Dim HDC1 As IntPtr = srcPic.GetHdc
    Dim HDC2 As IntPtr = srcMem.GetHdc

    BitBlt(HDC2, 0, 0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height, HDC1, 0, 0, 13369376)

    pnlDraw.BackgroundImage = srcBmp

    'Clean Up code omitted...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it's not possible to copy the contents of a Graphics object anywhere using any method, because a Graphics object doesn't contain anything.

Why don't use the DrawToBitmap method to draw the control on the bitmap?

```
Dim srcBmp As New Bitmap(pnl.Width, pnl.Height)
Dim clip As New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), pnl.Size)
pnl.DrawToBitmap(srcBmp, clip)
```