# How to print panel in windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I Have windows form but i want to print panel in windows form  to hidden print button and it's my code :

```
   private void printDoc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(this.streamToPrint);
        int x = e.MarginBounds.X;
        int y = e.MarginBounds.Y;
        int width = image.Width;
        int height = image.Height;
        if ((width / e.MarginBounds.Width) > (height / e.MarginBounds.Height))
        {
            width = e.MarginBounds.Width;
            height = image.Height * e.MarginBounds.Width / image.Width;
        }
        else
        {
            height = e.MarginBounds.Height;
            width = image.Width * e.MarginBounds.Height / image.Height;
        }
        System.Drawing.Rectangle destRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    public void StartPrint(Stream streamToPrint, string streamType)
    {
        this.printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDoc_PrintPage);


        this.streamToPrint = streamToPrint;
        this.streamType = streamType;
        System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog PrintDialog1 = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDialog1.AllowSomePages = true;
        PrintDialog1.ShowHelp = true;
        PrintDialog1.Document = printDoc;

        DialogResult result = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDoc.Print();
            //docToPrint.Print();
        }

    }

    private void button_Print_Certificate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          Graphics g1 = this.CreateGraphics();
        Image MyImage = new Bitmap(this.ClientRectangle.Width,      this.ClientRectangle.Height, g1);
        Graphics g2 = Graphics.FromImage(MyImage);
        IntPtr dc1 = g1.GetHdc();
        IntPtr dc2 = g2.GetHdc();
        BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, dc1, 0, 0, 13369376);
        g1.ReleaseHdc(dc1);
        g2.ReleaseHdc(dc2);
        MyImage.Save(@"D:\PrintPage.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"D:\PrintPage.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StartPrint(fileStream, "Image");
        fileStream.Close();

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"D:\PrintPage.jpg"))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(@"D:\PrintPage.jpg");
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what's the question?  How is the panel you mentioned in your title related?  What is the difference between what the code you posted does and what you want?

Comment: i want to print panel in my winform but this code print all form with button print

Comment: Try replacing all occurrences of `this` in `button_Print_Certificate_Click` with the panel object.

Comment: thank u Ben voiagt  it's print panel only

Comment: Ok, I've turned that idea into an actual answer.  Is everything working correctly now>

Answer (score 0):

In order to print a particular control, you'll want to use that control as the source of your BitBlt operation.

So instead of `this.CreateGraphics()`, call `panel.CreateGraphics()`.  Similarly, use `panel.ClientRectangle` to get the width and height of the image.

But take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/597088/103167 which gives you an easier way.